# Ruby: Sorting a multidimensional array which may contain nil sometimes fails

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I found this example in a failing test in one of my projects. Why does this work:

```
[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,1,nil]].sort
#=> [[1, 1, nil], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

But this does not:

```
[[1,2,3], [nil,3,4], [1,1,nil]].sort
#=> ERROR: ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
```

Tested Ruby versions: `2.0.0`, `1.9.3`.

Comment: @majioa avoid answering in the comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's failing because it's going over the `nil`. The reason the first test example doesn't fail is because the comparison of `1, 1` happens with `1, 2`. It doesn't go as far as the `nil` to verify because it doesn't need to.

The example below fails because it must go over `nil` initially. Try it out in irb:

```
[1, nil, 2].sort
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

# in this example 1,2 comes before 2,1 so no need to continue in sort
# and nil is never reached
[ [2,1,3,5], [1,2,nil,6] ].sort
 => [[1, 2, nil, 6], [2, 1, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: Well, here is way to solve this:  `[1,2, nil].sort {|x, y| x.to_i<=>y.to_i}` as someone may looking for this.

Comment: Even shorter: `[1,2,nil].sort_by &:to_i`

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the comparison between the arrays in order to sort them, it's element to element:

In the first case `[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,1,nil]].sort`, the algorithm compares:

```
1 (of the first array) < 2 (of the second array)
1 (of the first array) = 1 (of the third array)
```

Then, as there are two elements equal, we have to compare the second element:

```
2 (of the first array) > 1 (of the third array)
```

Then the comparison finishes, no need to compare the 3th element.

Now, in the second case `[[1,2,3], [nil,3,4], [1,1,nil]].sort`, the comparison of the first element of the arrays contains a nil, and this will raise an error.

For example, this will raise an error:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,nil,4], [3,1,3]].sort
```

This wont:

```
[[2,2,3], [1,nil,4], [3,1,3]].sort
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `#sort` method uses [*QSort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) sorting methodics, and in come cases the sort procedure reach not the last value of array. In your case `[1,1,nil]` it is `nil`. And it reach to `nil` in case `1,nil,4`, because in last case `#<=>` method returns `nil`. To avoid the error, you need to redefine `Array`'s `#<=>` method, or use complex block:

```
[[1,2,3], [nil,3,4], [1,1,nil]].sort do| x, y |
   x <=> y || 1
end
```